# Powershell Recursion

Tags: powershell

I need help with powershell recursion.  Below is a program i am starting to write and i need to be able to do work on each item. Instead for GCI -Recurse seems to just return a list of the files and not allow me to do anything with them afterwards

```
cls
$pattern = "^(.*)_(\d{8})(.*)$"



$files = "X:\" 

gci -path $files -recurse -Include "*.tif"

foreach($file in $files){


    if($file.Name -match $pattern){
        Write-Host $Matches[1]
    }   



}
```

Any insight as to why i am only receiving a list and not the $Matches[1] would be great. 
Thanks

Comment: You aren't storing the result of `gci` anywhere. You are iterating over `X:\` in that loop.

Comment: Note that `gci -path $files -recurse -Include "*.tif" | where-object { $_.Name -match $pattern; }` is probably a lot more efficient than building your own loop.

Comment: @BaconBits - ah sorry, I was just posting that as an answer and afterwards saw you had commented the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code doesn't make sense. `$files` is set to `X:\` and never changed so I don't know what your foreach will iterate.

This should work:

```
$pattern = "^(.*)_(\d{8})(.*)$"
$files = gci -path X:\ -recurse -Include "*.tif"

foreach($file in $files){

    if($file.Name -match $pattern){
        Write-Host $Matches[1]

    }   
}
```

Comment: Yea that was silly of me..... it was just displaying a list of each file. testing now.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be shortened to

```
$files = gci -path "C:\Temp" -recurse -Include "*.txt" 
               | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $pattern }
```

Comment: That won't output the relevant part of the matched file name